# caml query won't return rows with null value in contains query

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

I have written a **CAML query** using `<Or>` with `<Contains>`.
the query looks similar to below:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
      <Or>
        <Contains><FieldRef Name="Field1" /><Value Type="Text">`
          +SearchTerms +`</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains><FieldRef Name="Field2" /><Value Type="Text">`
          +SearchTerms +`</Value>
        </Contains>
      </Or>
      <Or>
      <Contains><FieldRef Name="field3" /><Value Type="Lookup">`
      +SearchTerms +`</Value>
    </Contains>
        <Contains><FieldRef Name="field4" /><Value Type="Lookup">`
          +SearchTerms +`</Value>
        </Contains>
      </Or>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

Basically what I want to do is return all rows that contain search terms in one of those four *fields(field1,field2,field3,field4)*.
for example if I SearchTerms is 'abc' then all rows where any of the fields contain abc should be returned.
This works most of the time.  It fails when there is an empty in field3 or field4.

Basically, if field1 and/or two meet the criteria, but field3 or field4 is empty it won't return that row.  It still returns rows if there are multiple rows. 
I've tried rearranging things and it doesn't seem to help.

I'm currently developing this in spfx.  When I check the json I am finding that the rows are not returned there.  I belive it is definately my Caml query.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I modified the question.  How do I go about getting the hold status removed?

Answer (score 0):

That could be because the field type is **Lookup** so it needs to find a matching value so it can return the information from the lookup list. You can try to use a default value for all those unmatching rows if it is really necessary to leave it blank.

Also make sure that you are getting the value correctly

```
 lookupValue = listItem["lookupColumn"] as FieldLookupValue;
       if (lookupValue != null)
          {
             foo.value = lookupValue.LookupValue;
          }
```

Comment: Thanks, Bailbrera,  I'm new to querying using Caml.  I'm not sure why the first thing you mention would be the case.  The contains are within an OR.  For item 2 I have viewed the JSON and unfortunately the rows just aren't returned.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to user `<AND>` at top of the query after `<WHERE>` like this.

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <AND>
      <Or>
        <Contains><FieldRef Name="Field1" /><Value Type="Text"> +SearchTerms +</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains><FieldRef Name="Field2" /><Value Type="Text"> +SearchTerms +</Value>
        </Contains>
      </Or>
      <Or>
      <Contains><FieldRef Name="field3" /><Value Type="Lookup"> +SearchTerms +</Value>
    </Contains>
        <Contains><FieldRef Name="field4" /><Value Type="Lookup"> +SearchTerms +</Value>
        </Contains>
      </Or>
    </AND>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that just doesn't logically make sense.  It really need to return the row if any of fields have the value.  An and seems to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `LookupId="TRUE"` to the `FieldRefs` for the lookup fields, like:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Or>
            <Contains><FieldRef Name="Field1" /><Value Type="Text">`
                + SearchTerms +`</Value>
            </Contains>
            <Contains><FieldRef Name="Field2" /><Value Type="Text">`
                + SearchTerms +`</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Or>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="field3" LookupId=”TRUE” /><Value Type="Lookup">`
                + Id + </Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="field4"  LookupId=”TRUE” /><Value Type="Lookup">`
                + Id + </Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

This would also require you're using the lookup `IDs` for the search terms of the lookup fields, and probably using `Eq` instead of `Contains` for those fields, which means you'd need an `OR` condition for each ID against each lookup. You might still be able to concat the `IDs` and use contains, but you'd definitely need to use `Ids` instead of `searchTerms`.

If that doesn't work, you could also add 2 additional OR tests, one for each lookup testing for `IsNull`, but I suspect the `LookupId="TRUE"` is the fix. Lookup fields used as filters have some strange behaviors when you don't specify `LookupId="TRUE"`.